# How to create page in customer account section Magento 2

Tags: magento2, layout, customer, xml

[image]

> I want to create new page and link to => HISTORY
>
> how i can do this??
>
> where I can add a new link?

Comment: Is that cms page?

Answer (score 0):

You can create **customer_account.xml** layout XML file with below content to insert a custom link in customer account section.

```
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
   <body>
      <referenceBlock name="customer_account_navigation">
         <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Html\Link\Current" name="customer-account-navigation-mycard">
            <arguments>
               <argument name="path" xsi:type="string">history/index/index</argument>
               <argument name="label" xsi:type="string">History</argument>               
                <argument name="class" xsi:type="string">customer_hostory</argument>
            </arguments>
         </block>
      </referenceBlock>
   </body>
</page>
```

On above XML:

**path** => URL path that you want to link

**label** => Text label to show for the custom link

**class** => CSS class name